# Math function with numericUpDown causeswrong number displaying in textBox

Tags: c#, winforms, math, numericupdown

I have an issue with textboxes and numericUpDown. I take the Value from first textBox1 (indBox) plus number from numericUpDown1 and display the result in another textBox2.

I need to use number 40000 in first textBox, but in result textBox, for instance I have 4000 (three zeroes, not four) untill I change the Value of numericUpDown. Only after changing the value I get correct count of numbers in my value. I use TextChanged event in first textbox. and the next code:

```
    private void indBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //
    {
        try
        {
            textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString( Convert.ToInt16(indBox.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(numericUpDown1.Value));

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Can not calculate";
        }
    }
```

Please help! Thank you! :)

Comment: I think you should do the calculation separately from the UI and only render the results. Don't parse textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum value of `Int16` is `32,767` and `40,000` exceed the maximum.

Use `Int32`

```
textBox3.Text = (int.Parse(indBox.Text) + (int)numericUpDown1.Value).ToString();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `NumericUpDown.Value` is of type `decimal`  so `int.parse` won't work. A cast will though. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thanks, fixed. I'd prefer casting and parsing over converting - it's a bit heavyweight

Comment: Completely with you on that one. Pet peeve of mine. Ever trace through all the methods that get called for something like `Convert.ToInt32(SomeEnumValue)`? it's crazy due to IConvertible and I don't think the compiler/jitter does any trickery with it.

Answer (score 0):

40000 is greater than the [`Int16`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.int16(v=vs.110).aspx) [maximum value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) (32767). You can use [`Int32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, which can store values up to [2147483647](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(indBox.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value));
```

Comment: What does this say that the other answer doesn't?

Comment: It uses `Convert.ToInt32` which, for me, is much cleaner than `int.Parse`. Also, when I started to create my answer there were no other answers.

Comment: You do realize `Convert.ToInt32` just calls `int.parse` right? So it's mostly an extra layer of indirection. There's also a semantic difference in that `Convert` will turn `null` into `0` whereas `parse` will throw an exception. For the case of `numericUpDown1.Value` it's using  `Convert.ToInt32(double)`. That just calls `Decimal.FCallToInt32` which is an `InternalCall`... But since it's **already** a `decimal` why not just cast instead of two extra method calls? How is any of that "cleaner"?

Comment: I just say is much cleaner for me, not faster. However, thank you @pinkfloydx33 for details.